# Devise automatic sign in after password reset not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My rails application have devise for user authentication. After reset password i need to automatically sign in to the user account. But here the session is not created.

My update action in password controller

```
def update
self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)
yield resource if block_given?
if resource.errors.empty?
  resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
  if Devise.sign_in_after_reset_password
    flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
    set_flash_message!(:notice, flash_message)
    resource.after_database_authentication
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  else
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :updated_not_active)
  end
  respond_with resource, location: after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
else
  set_minimum_password_length
  respond_with resource
end
end
```

i have set `sign_in_after_reset_password` to `true` in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

Can anyone help with what i'm missing here.?

Comment: Did you restart rails server after changing the config?

Comment: It should work automatically, without changing anything. Also if your passwords controller is inheriting from Devise::PasswordsController, you don't even need to write the update action at all. [Here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L33) is all your code.